# Unable to Boot - Stuck on "[sda] Assuming drive cache: write through"

Tags: boot, cache

How do I boot to Ubuntu desktop?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on VMWare Workstation. It was running fine until I had to expand my hard drive. Then, it showed the "SMBus Host Controller not enabled!" error which I fixed using blacklist i2c-piix4.

However, after reboot, it gets stuck at "Assume drive cache: write through". Please see the image below. Any ideas how to fix it? I tried everything I can think of, including adding 'blacklist intel_powerclamp" and increasing memory, but still gets stuck on "Assuming drive cache:.." every time I boot.  Please help me.